# Why does the HTML file render differently through Django and when opened directly?

Tags: html, django

When I run the below HTML file via Django's render function, I get the following result: [Django result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbyxM.jpg)

However, when I open the HTML file directly by clicking on it, I get the following result: [HTML result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voYND.jpg)

Why do they render so differently? How should I modify the code such that when I render the HTML file through Django, I can obtain the same result as when I open the HTML file directly?`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.82.0">
    <title>Headers · Bootstrap v5.0</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/headers/">



    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Favicons -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="180x180">
<link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
<link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
<link rel="manifest" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#7952b3">
<link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#7952b3">


    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>


    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/headers/headers.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="bootstrap" viewBox="0 0 118 94">
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M24.509 0c-6.733 0-11.715 5.893-11.492 12.284.214 6.14-.064 14.092-2.066 20.577C8.943 39.365 5.547 43.485 0 44.014v5.972c5.547.529 8.943 4.649 10.951 11.153 2.002 6.485 2.28 14.437 2.066 20.577C12.794 88.106 17.776 94 24.51 94H93.5c6.733 0 11.714-5.893 11.491-12.284-.214-6.14.064-14.092 2.066-20.577 2.009-6.504 5.396-10.624 10.943-11.153v-5.972c-5.547-.529-8.934-4.649-10.943-11.153-2.002-6.484-2.28-14.437-2.066-20.577C105.214 5.894 100.233 0 93.5 0H24.508zM80 57.863C80 66.663 73.436 72 62.543 72H44a2 2 0 01-2-2V24a2 2 0 012-2h18.437c9.083 0 15.044 4.92 15.044 12.474 0 5.302-4.01 10.049-9.119 10.88v.277C75.317 46.394 80 51.21 80 57.863zM60.521 28.34H49.948v14.934h8.905c6.884 0 10.68-2.772 10.68-7.727 0-4.643-3.264-7.207-9.012-7.207zM49.948 49.2v16.458H60.91c7.167 0 10.964-2.876 10.964-8.281 0-5.406-3.903-8.178-11.425-8.178H49.948z"></path>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="home" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M8.354 1.146a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0l-6 6A.5.5 0 0 0 1.5 7.5v7a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h4.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-4h2v4a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H14a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-7a.5.5 0 0 0-.146-.354L13 5.793V2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.293L8.354 1.146zM2.5 14V7.707l5.5-5.5 5.5 5.5V14H10v-4a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v4H2.5z"></path>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="speedometer2" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V4.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4zM3.732 5.732a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l.915.914a.5.5 0 1 1-.708.708l-.914-.915a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.707zM2 10a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1.586a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H2.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 10zm9.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H12a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm.754-4.246a.389.389 0 0 0-.527-.02L7.547 9.31a.91.91 0 1 0 1.302 1.258l3.434-4.297a.389.389 0 0 0-.029-.518z"></path>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 10a8 8 0 1 1 15.547 2.661c-.442 1.253-1.845 1.602-2.932 1.25C11.309 13.488 9.475 13 8 13c-1.474 0-3.31.488-4.615.911-1.087.352-2.49.003-2.932-1.25A7.988 7.988 0 0 1 0 10zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-6.603 9.329c.203.575.923.876 1.68.63C4.397 12.533 6.358 12 8 12s3.604.532 4.923.96c.757.245 1.477-.056 1.68-.631A7 7 0 0 0 8 3z"></path>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="table" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M0 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2zm15 2h-4v3h4V4zm0 4h-4v3h4V8zm0 4h-4v3h3a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-2zm-5 3v-3H6v3h4zm-5 0v-3H1v2a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h3zm-4-4h4V8H1v3zm0-4h4V4H1v3zm5-3v3h4V4H6zm4 4H6v3h4V8z"></path>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="people-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M11 6a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0z"></path>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 8a8 8 0 1 1 16 0A8 8 0 0 1 0 8zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-5.468 11.37C3.242 11.226 4.805 10 8 10s4.757 1.225 5.468 2.37A7 7 0 0 0 8 1z"></path>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="grid" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M1 2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 2.5 1h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 7 2.5v3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5.5 7h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1 5.5v-3zM2.5 2a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3zm6.5.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 10.5 1h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 15 2.5v3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 13.5 7h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 9 5.5v-3zm1.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3zM1 10.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 2.5 9h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 7 10.5v3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5.5 15h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1 13.5v-3zm1.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3zm6.5.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 10.5 9h3a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5 1.5v3a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 9 13.5v-3zm1.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3z"></path>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<div class="container">
  <header class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center py-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
    <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-dark text-decoration-none">
      <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
      <span class="fs-4">Simple header</span>
    </a>

    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link active">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Features</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">FAQs</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</div>

<div class="b-example-divider"></div>

<div class="container">
  <header class="d-flex justify-content-center py-3">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link active">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Features</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">FAQs</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</div>

<div class="b-example-divider"></div>

<div class="container">
  <header class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-md-between py-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
    <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center col-md-3 mb-2 mb-md-0 text-dark text-decoration-none">
      <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
    </a>

    <ul class="nav col-12 col-md-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 link-secondary">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 link-dark">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 link-dark">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 link-dark">FAQs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 link-dark">About</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-end">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary me-2">Login</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign-up</button>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>

<div class="b-example-divider"></div>

<header class="p-3 bg-dark text-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
      <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-white text-decoration-none">
        <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
      </a>

      <ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-secondary">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">About</a></li>
      </ul>

      <form class="col-12 col-lg-auto mb-3 mb-lg-0 me-lg-3">
        <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-dark" placeholder="Search...">
      </form>

      <div class="text-end">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light me-2">Login</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Sign-up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="b-example-divider"></div>

<header class="p-3 mb-3 border-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
      <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-dark text-decoration-none">
        <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
      </a>

      <ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 link-secondary">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 link-dark">Inventory</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 link-dark">Customers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 link-dark">Products</a></li>
      </ul>

      <form class="col-12 col-lg-auto mb-3 mb-lg-0 me-lg-3">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
      </form>

      <div class="dropdown text-end">
        <a href="#" class="d-block link-dark text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="mdo" width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle">
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu text-small" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project...</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
          <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="b-example-divider"></div>

<header class="py-3 mb-3 border-bottom">
  <div class="container-fluid d-grid gap-3 align-items-center" style="grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center col-lg-4 mb-2 mb-lg-0 link-dark text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownNavLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownNavLink">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item active" href="#">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Inventory</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Customers</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Analytics</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
      <form class="w-100 me-3">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
      </form>

      <div class="flex-shrink-0 dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="d-block link-dark text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="mdo" width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle">
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser2">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project...</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
          <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<main class="container-fluid pb-3">
  <div class="d-grid gap-3" style="grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;">
    <div class="bg-light border rounded-3">
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-light border rounded-3">
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<div class="b-example-divider"></div>

<nav class="py-2 bg-light border-bottom">
  <div class="container d-flex flex-wrap">
    <ul class="nav me-auto">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark px-2 active">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark px-2">Features</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark px-2">Pricing</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark px-2">FAQs</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark px-2">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark px-2">Login</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark px-2">Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<header class="py-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
  <div class="container d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
    <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-dark text-decoration-none">
      <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
      <span class="fs-4">Double header</span>
    </a>
    <form class="col-12 col-lg-auto mb-3 mb-lg-0">
      <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
    </form>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="b-example-divider"></div>

<header class="px-3 py-2 bg-dark text-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
      <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center my-2 my-lg-0 me-lg-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
        <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
      </a>

      <ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto my-2 justify-content-center my-md-0 text-small">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link text-secondary">
            <svg class="bi d-block mx-auto mb-1" width="24" height="24"><use xlink:href="#home"></use></svg>
            Home
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
            <svg class="bi d-block mx-auto mb-1" width="24" height="24"><use xlink:href="#speedometer2"></use></svg>
            Dashboard
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
            <svg class="bi d-block mx-auto mb-1" width="24" height="24"><use xlink:href="#table"></use></svg>
            Orders
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
            <svg class="bi d-block mx-auto mb-1" width="24" height="24"><use xlink:href="#grid"></use></svg>
            Products
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
            <svg class="bi d-block mx-auto mb-1" width="24" height="24"><use xlink:href="#people-circle"></use></svg>
            Customers
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="px-3 py-2 border-bottom mb-3">
  <div class="container d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
    <form class="col-12 col-lg-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 me-lg-auto">
      <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
    </form>

    <div class="text-end">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light text-dark me-2">Login</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign-up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="b-example-divider"></div>

    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body></html>
```

`

The code above is taken from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/headers/.